There is no raw query execution function
I have a project with .NET Core 3.1 that worked with Oracle DB which uses these libraries:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore               v5.0.12
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design        v5.0.12
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational    v5.0.12
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer     v3.1.21
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools         v5.0.12
Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore                  v5.21.4

My Context.DataBase does not have an ExecuteSqlRaw function

Also, inside the model, it does not have the function of the FromSqlRaw:

Why can't I access the ExecuteSqlRaw function?

I updated Visual Studio 2018 to Visual Studio 2022 and the problem was solved.

